# Como fazer Ctrl+S salvar no Vim?

Tags: vim

Quando uso Vim no terminal e aciono <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, ou o terminal trava ou acontece alguma outra coisa estranha.

Como apertar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> já é quase um instinto para salvar, como fazer para mapear esse atalho para salvar o arquivo?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Ctrl-S` é um atalho para ativar o scroll-lock do terminal desde quando os terminais eram mais lentos em exibir os caracteres do que os operadores em digitá-los. Para desligar o scroll-lock, basta pressionar `Ctrl-Q`.

Como a necessidade é utilizar essa combinação de teclas no Vim, é necessário configurar o terminal desabilitar o scroll-lock em alguns terminais, como o `xterm`. Isso pode ser feito adicionando a opção `allowScrollLock: "false"` no arquivo `~/.Xresources`.

Depois disso, basta configurar o Vim (arquivo ~/.vimrc) com map!:

```
map! <C-s> <ESC>:w<CR>
```

Nota: se for necessário mapear para todos os modos do Vim, é necessário utilizar o `map!` e o `map`, o primeiro é utilizado para os modos de Inserção e Linha de Comando, o segundo para os modos Normal, Visual/Seleção e Comandos Pendentes.

Comment: É, consegui desabilitar o scroll-lock, mas o Ctrl-S continua sem salvar. Você conseguiu fazer funcionar aí?

Comment: Editei a resposta para incluir o ```map```, que salva nos modos Normal e Visual/Seleção.

Comment: Cara, aqui ainda não está funcionando, em nenhum modo. Está funcionando pra vocë salvar com Ctrl-S?

Comment: Sim, aqui funciona com ambos os map[!].Estou utilizando o Vim 7.4 no Debian Testing.

Comment: Vim 7.4 tbm, no Ubuntu aqui. Rapaz, que estranho. Aqui ele está funcionando como um Esc. Eu faço a sequencia <C-S>:q e ele dá "No write since last change".

Comment: Estranho, deveria funcionar. as únicas configs que alterei no meu ```.vimrc``` foram: ```map! <C-S> <ESC>:w<CR>``` e ```map <C-S> <ESC>:w<CR>```. e tudo funcionou como o esperado, em todos os modos.

Comment: Opa! Limpei o vimrc e deixei só esses comandos e agora funcionou!

Comment: Devia ter algum plugin mocoziando a parada. Beleza, answer accepted -- valeu! =)

Answer (score 5):

Eu acho que o problema é que o Ctrl+S é o atalho do comando "Stop", e por isso está travando o seu terminal. Você já tentou utilizar o comando "stty" (http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?stty+1) para configurar o terminal?

Eu não consigo testar aqui, mas me parece que uma possibilidade é criar um script que faça algo como:

```
stty -ixon
vim
stty ixon
```

Segundo a documentação do stty, a opção ixon faz o seguinte:

```
 ixon (-ixon)          Enable  (disable)  START/STOP   output
                       control.  Output is stopped by sending
                       STOP control character and started  by
                       sending the START control character.
```

Comment: Isso, `stty -ixon` desabilita o scroll-lock do Ctrl-S que o Bruno falou na resposta dele. Só falta ver como mapear o atalho pra salvar. Valeu! =)

Comment: +1 pela dica do `stty -ixon` -- tô usando isso pra desabilitar o scroll lock.

Comment: Legal! Fico feliz que foi de alguma ajuda. :)

Answer (score 1):

No Vim você salva assim (só precisa do ESC se você não estiver no modo de comandos):

<kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>:w</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: Sim, eu sei como salvar no vim. A pergunta é como mapear `Ctrl-S` para **também** salvar, em vez de bagunçar o terminal.

Comment: É, `nmap` é a primeira ideia, mas só funciona no modo normal, né? Eu queria que funcionasse no modo de inserção também.

Comment: Achei que você estava perguntando como salvava no vim, mas pelo visto você manja mais que eu :-) O que eu faria seria usar o atalho estilo vim mesmo. Você tem de entrar em "modo vim" para usar o vim... @elias

Comment: Heheh! O problema é a memória muscular, Ctrl-S é quase automático.

Answer (score 1):

Eu usaria `:inoremap <c-s> <c-o>:update<CR><CR>`