# Como salvar e sair no VIM?

Tags: vim

Estou com um problema (acho que é um problema) no editor de texto do vim.

Quando crio um arquivo `readme.md` e depois faço o comando `vim readme.md`, abre o editor e aí começa o problema.

Quando digito algo ali dentro não sei qual o comando para salvar e sair, para voltar pro Git bash.

Comment: o vim é bem chato de usar, deve usar "i" para editar, e apertar as teclas ESC : w q ENTER para salvar e sair https://woliveiras.com.br/posts/Comecando-com-o-editor-de-texto-VIM/

Comment: Po , muito obrigado , funcionou . Eu tentei salvar o sublme como editor de texto mas não consegui , você saberia dizer qual o comando ou como fazer para que o sublime vire o editor ? Obrigado .

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Como fazer Ctrl-S salvar no Vim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149/3635) - (não é dup, apenas relacionado)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Para sair do vim você precisa usar `:q` no modo de comando. Para salvar é `:w`. Portanto, para sair e salvar é `:wq`.

Se você não souber se está no modo de comando ou no modo de inserção, é possível ir "direto" para o **modo de comando** usando a combinação <kbd>**Esc**</kbd> + <kbd>**Esc**</kbd>.

Ou seja

<kbd>**Esc**</kbd> + <kbd>**Esc**</kbd>
<kbd>**:**</kbd> + <kbd>**w**</kbd> + <kbd>**q**</kbd> + <kbd>**Enter**</kbd>

Comment: Então eu usei/escrevi esse comando e apertei enter , mas ele "pula" de linha e continua no editor .

Comment: @MatheusMacedo Adicionei um parágrafo

Comment: Obrigado , funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

```
:wq    --> Salvar e sair.
:x     --> Salvar e Sair.
:wqa   --> Salva e sai de todos os arquivos que estiverem abertos.
```

Answer (score 0):

Abrir um arquivo grande, esse foi aberto sem permissão para salvar. Alterei o arquivo. o comando `:w` geral um erro de permissão, o  `:q` não sai porque o arquivo não está salvo.

Para sair do vim de qualquer forma

```
:q!  --> sair sem salvar
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Para sair do git de maneira fácil após ter entrado em modo de inserção `esc` depois `i`  e digitado sua mensagem de commit , basta apertar `esc` novamente depois `ZZ` maiusculo.